# Creating java regex to get href link

Tags: java, html, regex, href, inverse

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find any answers on the web.  I'm having a hard time figuring out the inverse to this regex:

> "\"[^>]*\">"

I want to use replaceAll to replace everything except the link.  So if I had a tag similar to this:

> `<p><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></p>`

I need a regex that would satisfy this:

> s.replaceAll(regex, "");

to give me this output:

> `http://www.google.com`

I know there are better ways to do this, but I have to use a regex.  Any help is really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You do not have to use `replaceAll`. Better use pattern groups like the following:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("href=\"(.*?)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
String url = null;
if (m.find()) {
    url = m.group(1); // this variable should contain the link URL
}
```

If you have several links into your HTML perform `m.find()` in loop.

Comment: Thanks, it was hard for me to implement it because I was already using a pattern/matcher to find specific links that end in .htm and .html.

Comment: Very useful! Thank you, Alex.

Answer (score 0):

If you always have one such link in a string, try this:

```
"(^[^\"]*\")|(\"[^\"]*)$"
```

Comment: This worked, but failed when the href tag had 'id=' before the link.  I should've added that to my question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use the method to get a map of all the properties of a HTML tag. Create a simple way to find all the properties of an HTML, like...

```
    Pattern linkPattern = Pattern.compile("<a (.*?)>");
    Matcher linkMatcher = linkPattern.matcher(in);
    while (linkMatcher.find()) { parseProperties(linkMatcher.group(1)).toString(); }
```

Get properties:

```
private static final Pattern PARSE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\s*?(\\w*?)\\s*?=\\s*?\"(.*?)\"");

public static Map<String, String> parseProperties (String in) {

  Map<String, String> out = new HashMap<>();

  // Create matcher based on parsing pattern
  Matcher matcher = PARSE_PATTERN.matcher(in);

  // Populate map
  while (matcher.find()) { out.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2)); }

  return out; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can checkout http://regexlib.com/ for all the regex help you need. And the one below is for url :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)$
```

Comment: The way it's currently written, that regex wouldn't work for site with country codes like winchester.us, amazon.co.uk, amazon.ca, etc.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I've made a mistake by imposing my practice.

Comment: Also, doesn't work with Java 6.0, at least not in the replaceAll method.

Comment: @user1070866, then that's the cherry on top for me.