# Read data from html page Android

Tags: java, android, html

I am browsing a ftp directory in a html-address and I want to list all the files without getting the html code also. This is my code now

```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
    URL oracle = null;
    try {
        oracle = new URL("http://mopedshowcase.com/Comments/Cross/1/");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String inputLine;
    try {
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            final String ass = inputLine;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                   Log.e("My : ",""+ass);
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        }}).start();
}
```

but this is the output

```
08-10 14:01:05.007    5655-5655/com.emiliogaines.mopedshowcase E/My :﹕ <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
08-10 14:01:05.007    5655-5655/com.emiliogaines.mopedshowcase E/My :﹕ <html>
08-10 14:01:05.007    5655-5655/com.emiliogaines.mopedshowcase E/My :﹕ <head>
08-10 14:01:05.008    5655-5655/com.emiliogaines.mopedshowcase E/My :﹕ <title>Index of /Comments/Cross/1</title>
08-10 14:01:05.008    5655-5655/com.emiliogaines.mopedshowcase E/My :﹕ </head>
08-10 14:01:05.008    5655-5655/com.emiliogaines.mopedshowcase E/My :﹕ <body>
08-10 14:01:05.008    5655-5655/com.emiliogaines.mopedshowcase E/My :﹕ <h1>Index of /Comments/Cross/1</h1>
08-10 14:01:05.008    5655-5655/com.emiliogaines.mopedshowcase E/My :﹕ <ul><li><a href="/Comments/Cross/"> Parent Directory</a></li>
08-10 14:01:05.008    5655-5655/com.emiliogaines.mopedshowcase E/My :﹕ <li><a href="%25!Emilio%25Gaines!%25466376720196163289492.txt"> %!Emilio%Gaines!%466376720196163289492.txt</a></li>
08-10 14:01:05.008    5655-5655/com.emiliogaines.mopedshowcase E/My :﹕ </ul>
08-10 14:01:05.008    5655-5655/com.emiliogaines.mopedshowcase E/My :﹕ </body></html>
```

how can I get the site content and not the html code also? 
Thanks

Comment: @Hacketo thats the point but I want the file names and not the html code

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307839/creating-java-regex-to-get-href-link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180514/how-to-list-ftp-directories-with-android

Comment: The first link is for URLs which is not the case.
The second link is using ftpClient which I do not want to use since it is slow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561608/how-to-get-list-of-files-directories-of-an-directory-url-in-java