# How to get the exact text of href attribute of tag a?

Tags: html, selenium, hyperlink

I am using selenium to get href attribute, lLinks are my web element that has a "href" attribute.

```
String url = lLinks.getAttrbute("href");
```

If the href of my 'a' tag is a relative path like `<a href='/home'>Home</a>`
, the url will return http://www.domain.com/home.

How do I get the url to just equal to the exact text of the href attribute?

Answer (score 6):

I think you cannot get that "href". Selenium only provides a full path or a relative path. See code below:

```
String href = linx.getAttribute("href");
System.out.println("Text is" + href);
String pathName = linx.getAttribute("pathname");
System.out.println("Text is" + pathName);
// Results
// Text is http://www.amazon.com/gp/yourstore/home/ref=nav_cs_ys/180-1519742-0316250
// Text is /gp/yourstore/home/ref=nav_cs_ys/180-1519742-0316250
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the pathname will give /gp/yourstore/etc even if the href actually contains http://www.amazon.com/. So if you are testing to se if the href is set to relative, this will not work

Comment: @andreasnico I don't get your point. Can you rephrase your comment?

Comment: @andreasnico I get your point now. As I mentioned, you cannot get the property "href". It allows you to get full path and relative path, not the property.

Answer (score 5):

You can obtain `href` attribute by reading the whole element:

```
lLinks.getAttribute("outerHTML")
```

Which gives you e.g.:

```
<a id="button-id" href="#">Click me!</a>
```

Then you can use [pattern matching to get the `href` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8307839/creating-java-regex-to-get-href-link#answer-8307936).